# LinkButton in GridView not picking correct value

Tags: asp.net

I am using link button to display a pdf report for selected Report Id from Grid view. On page load I am binding the datasource with Gridview. By clicking the link button it fetches the correct report id from column 0 and displays the report. After sorting the grid the grid view shows the sorted data. Now if i click the link button it is not picking the changed value from column 0. instead it is picking the value before sorted.

Say: Column 0 has values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 before sorting. If i click link button of Row 3 before sorting it is picking value 3 from column 0. After sorting it is 3,4,5,2,1. Now if i click link button of row 3 it is still picking value 3 instead of 5. Can you please help me.

Below is my code:
aspx:

CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bindGrid();
}
protected void GvStockTakingReport_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

            GvStockTakingReport.DataSource = null;
            GvStockTakingReport.DataBind();
            GvStockTakingReport.Dispose();
            DataSet ds = StockTakingList.BindStocktakingReportGrid();
            DataTable dtSortTable = ds.Tables[0];
            if (dtSortTable != null)
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
                dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString();
                //ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                //Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                GvStockTakingReport.DataSource = dv;
                GvStockTakingReport.DataBind();
            }                      
       }

   protected void PrintReport(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

            LinkButton lkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow item = (GridViewRow)lkButton.NamingContainer;

            string Id = (item.FindControl("lblstk_id") as Label).Text;

            //Getting value for Id    
            string Id1 = e.CommandArgument.ToString();


            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32((string)e.CommandArgument);


            //string Id1 = Convert.ToString(GvStockTakingReport.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text);

            string Id2 = ((Label)(GvStockTakingReport.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblstk_id"))).Text;

            //Getting value for Id

            string virtualPath = string.Format("~/{0}/{1}{2}", Portal.Business, Portal.Core.Profile.ReportsDirectory, "General/RPT_03002_StockTakinReport.rpt");
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);

            using (ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument())
            {
                report.Load(physicalPath);
                Core.Security.CrystalReportLogOn(report, (SqlConnectionStringBuilder)Portal.Core.Profile.ConnectionStrings["MTServer"]);
                report.SetParameterValue("@STK_Id", Id);
                report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Page.Response, true, "Stock Taking report");
            }          
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of your GridView?  I would like to make sure that you are setting the item's CommandArgument properly (since you are using that to determine the 'rowIndex`).

Comment: Thanks for your response jeuton. I have resolved the issue.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. the issue whenever i click the link button the page load calls bindgrid method which resets the gridview to original sorting before the printreport method invokes. I have included the sorting logic in bindgrid method as well as below which resolved the issue.

Comment: Good deal.  My guess was that you weren't "resetting" the value of the CommandArgument in each or your rows when the rows were sorted (always assigning the CommandArgument the same value when the grid was bound).

Answer (score 0):

the issue was whenever i click the link button the page load calls
bindgrid method which resets the gridview to original sorting before the printreport method invokes. 
I have included the sorting logic in bindgrid method as well as below which resolved the issue.

```
   public void bindGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = StockTakingList.BindStocktakingReportGrid();
            GvStockTakingReport.DataSource = ds;
            GvStockTakingReport.DataBind();

            //To make sure the grid remains with sorting order while pageload method invokes otherwise it will reset to original order
            DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            if (dv != null)
            {
                if (ViewState["sortExpression"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["sortExpression"] = "STK_Id"; //First time it will sort by STK_ID i.e on first time page loading
                }

                if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";//First time it will sort ascending i.e on first time page loading
                }

                dv.Sort = ViewState["sortExpression"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString();
                GvStockTakingReport.DataSource = dv;
                GvStockTakingReport.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.Visible = true;
            error.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```